# How to pass back list of items as model from view to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have a model (see below) and the user should be able to look at a single spend details (already working with ajax and is dropdown driven). Once the spend details are loaded they should be able to enter in either a total amount for that details, or break it down by category (which is coming from a different model (SpendCategories) that is prepopulated). I first iterate through the categories to pull them back and for each row I map the SpendCategoryName to the SpendCategory in the SpendBreakdown.cs. I am trying to iterate and generate textarea per SpendCategory name and then send back the whole model (budgets).

**Problem**

When I run this it gives me an argument out of range exeception on the HiddenFor line in the for loop. I just need a way to save the amounts and categories on post back. Unfortunately I am new to MVC and cannot change the way the model is set up. Everything is working except for this piece.

I had to scrub some of this down for privacy purposes but please let me know if you need clarification

**Model**

```
public class Budgets : Financials
{
    public Spend Spending { get; set; }
    public SpendDetails SpendingDetails { get; set; }
    public List<SpendBreakdown> SpendingBreakdown{ get; set; }
}
```

**Spend.cs**

```
public int SpendId {get; set;}
public List<SpendCategories> SpendCategories {get; set;}
```

**SpendCategories.cs** (PRE POPULATED DATA)

```
public int SpendCategoryId {get; set;}
public string SpendCategoryName {get; set;}
public string SpendCategoryDescription {get; set;}
```

**SpendDetails.cs**

```
public int SpendDetailsId {get; set;}
public int SpendId {get; set;}
public string SpendDetailName {get; set;}
public int SpendBreakdownId {get; set;}
public decimal TotalSpendAmount {get; set;}
```

**SpendBreakdown.cs**

```
public int SpendBreakdownId {get; set;}
public int SpendDetailsId {get; set;}
public decimal SpendBreakdownAmount {get; set;}
public string SpendCategory {get; set;}
```

**Partial View** on the main page that is calling this partial is has the submit form

```
    <div class="row col-md-5">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="dt-head-center">Category:</th>
                    <th>Total Amount: </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SpendDetails.SpendCategories)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.SpendDetails.TotalSpendAmount)</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row totals">
    <div class="table-responsive col-md-6">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive" id="tblSpendSummary" summary="Spend Summary" style="padding-left: 10px;">
            <thead>
                <tr class="summary-header">
                    <th class="dt-head-center">Spend Category Name</th>
                    <th class="dt-head-center">Spend Breakdown Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @foreach (var cat in Model.Spend.SpendCategories)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@cat.SpendCategoryName- @cat.SpendCategoryDescription</td>

                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Spend.SpendCategories.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SpendBreakdown[i].SpendCategory, new { @Value = @cat.SpendCategoryDescription })
                            @*@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SpendBreakdown[i].SpendBreakdownId)*@
                            <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.SpendBreakdown[i].SpendBreakdownAmount)</td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UI**
[image]

**Controller** (Called to populate the model on dropdownlist change

```
public ActionResult BudgetTotalAmount(int spendDetailsId)
    {
        var SpendId = _executionRepository.RetrieveSpendIdBySpendDetailsId (spendDetailsId).SpendId;

        var model = new Budgets
        {
            Spending = _executionRepository.RetrieveSpendIdBySpendDetailsId(spendDetailsId),
            SpendingDetails = _executionRepository.RetrieveSpendSpendDetailsBySpendDetailsId(spendDetailsId),
            SpendingBreakdown = _executionRepository.RetrieveSpendBreakdown(spendId, spendDetailsId)
        };

        return PartialView("Budgets/_SpendBudgetsTotalAmounts", model);
    }
```

Comment: Is your controller action method receiving the model?  Or what?

Comment: @devlincarnate currently no, I am getting an argument out of range exception on the first in the first line under the FOR loop. when I tried this earlier with 1 category before  public List<SpendBreakdown> SpendingBreakdown was a list it was getting everything back just fine. But now that SpendingBreakdown is a list I am having issues

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `Count` of `SpendCategories` for the index:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Spend.SpendCategories.Count(); i++)
```

but you are actually indexing `SpendBReakdown`:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SpendBreakdown[i].SpendCategory, new { @Value = @cat.SpendCategoryDescription })
```

These two items do not have the same number of items, so the index is going beyond the end of `SpendBreakdown`. Make sure those are populated correctly if they are supposed to correlate. Otherwise, just use a `foreach` on `SpendBreakdowns`.

Comment: how can I get those 2 to correlate? I need the textareas for each of the SpendCategories (there are 10) Right now SpendBreakdowns has nothing in it yet

Comment: When you populate your Model, you will have to make sure that the correct data is loaded into `SpendBreakdown`. I would have to see the code that does that to see what is wrong there.

Comment: updated with controller that is populating the model

Comment: It looks like you are retrieving the `SpendBreakdown` based on `spendId` and `spendDetailsId`, but again indexing on the number of categories. I think you are assuming that there will be one `SpendBreakdown` per category, but that is not happening when you retrieve it from the DB. Can't you just change the `for` loop to a `foreach` loop on `SpendBreakdown`? There doesn't seem to be a reason to index on `SpendCategories.Count()`.

Comment: I have read somewhere that in order to return all of the breakdowns I would need to use a for loop. I will try now with your suggestion

Comment: actually, there will be 1 breakdown per category. when I go to insert into the database each category will have an amount. there are 10 categories and I want to insert the category and the amount all separate

Comment: I just want to create a text area per category and then pass them all back

Comment: The probably what is happening is that there are not `SpendBreakdown`s for each category yet, so the indexing fails. You would need to index for foreach on the categories (which you are doing) to make a textarea for each `SpendBreakdown`/`Category` combination.

Comment: how can I fix this?